# Простейший POST-запрос Java Android

Tags: php, java, android, post

Есть мобильное приложение для Android, написанное на Java. Требуется отправить из него данные php-скрипту методом POST. В формате json передавать необязательно, если можно обойтись без него.
Примеров вроде много, но в основном они устаревшие и очень громоздкие. Прошу привести самый простейший пример для решения этой задачи.
Были попытки сделать [как описано здесь](https://prodevsblog.com/view/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial/), запрос проходит, но пустой. В php принимаю вот так:

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$param1 = $info["param1"];
```

Далее данные отправляются в БД и там везде нули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ (для примера и без использования json) - использовать библиотеку [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Подключаем к проекту:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12' // если не нужна поддержка android 4, можно использовать версии 4.8.0 +
```

Пишем метод, который будет обращаться к серверу в интернете, в отдельном (не UI) потоке, например действие по кнопке:

```
public void postQueryExample(View view){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String myString="данные которые будет принимать и обрабатывать сервер";
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("param1", myString)
                .add("param2", "другие данные для примера")
                .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com/postquery.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
            try {
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                String stringResponse = response.body().string(); //в этой переменной будет ответ сервера
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Запрос должен обязательно идти через `https` - иначе, нужно прописывать [usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)

**PHP**

postquery.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['param1'])){
   $param1 = $_POST['param1']; //сначала нужно получить данные, а после обрабатывать, например json_decode
   echo 'param1='.$param1;
   if ( isset($_POST['param2'])){
       echo 'param2='.$_POST['param2'];
   }
   // и т.д.
}
else {
   echo "param1 is empty";
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось!